# How can i run worker service app in asp.net core mvc app with a Process(System.Diagnostics.Process)?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have 2 projects in my solution : 1 project (myWebApp) with asp.net core mvc and another project(myWorker) with worker service. I want to launch myWorker project from myWebApp project. suppose that myWebApp send data (3 numbers) to myWorker and myWorker calculate the sum of these three numbers and save the result in a file.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Why do you want this? Use a Windows Service to do work on the server, or tell ASP.NET you want to run work on the background. Also, a "worker service" in the context of a web application generally means something that runs in the browser. You cannot do _that_ using Process.Start(); such processes run on the server.

Comment: When I used the Process it didn't work. what should I use to make the two apps communicate?